# how to stratify variable by group into new variables?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

In R (dplyr, data.table, etc) how to go from:

```
group   var
a   0
a   0
a   1
a   0
b   1
b   1
b   0
c   1
c   0
c   1
c   1
```

to:

[image]

preferably, dynamically, so with a variable number of groups for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
d <- data.frame(group=sample(LETTERS[1:4],100,TRUE), var = rnorm(100))

groupInds <- split(1:NROW(d),d$group)

newColumns <- do.call("cbind",lapply(1:length(groupInds), function(k) {
  newColValues <- rep(NA,NROW(d)) #some init, you left blank, so I thought of NAs
  inds <- groupInds[[k]]
  newColValues[inds] <- d$var[inds]
  data.frame(newColValues)
}))
names(newColumns) <- paste0(names(groupInds),"_var")

newdf <- cbind(d,newColumns)
```

Its everything in base R. If you know that you can use a matrix, you can leave out the cast to a `data.frame` because of performance and instead of resetting the `names`, use `colnames`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `bdiag` after splitting by 'group'

```
library(Matrix)
m1 <- as.matrix(bdiag(split(df1$var, df1$group)))
colnames(m1) <- paste0(unique(df1$group), "_var")
cbind(df1, m1)
```

-output

```
#   group var a_var b_var c_var
#1      a   0     0     0     0
#2      a   0     0     0     0
#3      a   1     1     0     0
#4      a   0     0     0     0
#5      b   1     0     1     0
#6      b   1     0     1     0
#7      b   0     0     0     0
#8      c   1     0     0     1
#9      c   0     0     0     0
#10     c   1     0     0     1
#11     c   1     0     0     1
```

---

In order to differentiate between the value '0' from the ones that created in scarce matrix, we could do some `replace`ment

```
m1 <- as.matrix(bdiag(split(na_if(df1$var, 0), df1$group)))
i1 <- is.na(m1)
i2 <- m1 == 0 & !is.na(m1)
m1[i1] <- 0
m1[i2] <- NA
colnames(m1) <- paste0(unique(df1$group), "_var")
cbind(df1, m1)
#  group var a_var b_var c_var
#1      a   0     0    NA    NA
#2      a   0     0    NA    NA
#3      a   1     1    NA    NA
#4      a   0     0    NA    NA
#5      b   1    NA     1    NA
#6      b   1    NA     1    NA
#7      b   0    NA     0    NA
#8      c   1    NA    NA     1
#9      c   0    NA    NA     0
#10     c   1    NA    NA     1
#11     c   1    NA    NA     1
```

---

or this can be done using `tidyverse` by splitting the data into a `list` of data.frame with `group` column, then rename the 'var' column and use `bind_rows` which will automatically add `NA` elements if the column is not found in the `list` element

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    group_split(group) %>% 
    map(~ .x %>% 
       rename(!! str_c(first(.x$group), '_var') := var) %>%
       select(-group)) %>%
    bind_rows %>% 
    bind_cols(df1, .)
```

-output

```
#   group var a_var b_var c_var
#1      a   0     0    NA    NA
#2      a   0     0    NA    NA
#3      a   1     1    NA    NA
#4      a   0     0    NA    NA
#5      b   1    NA     1    NA
#6      b   1    NA     1    NA
#7      b   0    NA     0    NA
#8      c   1    NA    NA     1
#9      c   0    NA    NA     0
#10     c   1    NA    NA     1
#11     c   1    NA    NA     1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(group = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", 
"c", "c", "c"), var = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative with "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
cbind(df1, as.data.table(df1)[
  , dcast(.SD, .I ~ paste0(group, "_var"), value.var = "var")][
  , ".I" := NULL])
#    group var a_var b_var c_var
# 1      a   0     0    NA    NA
# 2      a   0     0    NA    NA
# 3      a   1     1    NA    NA
# 4      a   0     0    NA    NA
# 5      b   1    NA     1    NA
# 6      b   1    NA     1    NA
# 7      b   0    NA     0    NA
# 8      c   1    NA    NA     1
# 9      c   0    NA    NA     0
# 10     c   1    NA    NA     1
# 11     c   1    NA    NA     1
```